# batch script error level output is not showing expected output

Tags: batch-file, cmd

```
@echo off
start cmd /V:ON /k "set /P id="Enter yes or no: "  && echo !id! && if !id!==yes (exit /b 0) else (exit /b 5)"`
```

Current result:

```
Enter yes or no: no
echo %errorlevel%
0
```

I have tried with both yes and no option, but after execution of code its not sending exit code 5.

Any solution for this problem?

Comment: Well, a batch script (run by `cmd.exe`) that runs the `start` command to start another `cmd.exe` instance to run further commands – is this really necessary?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly how you're trying to implement this, but it seems to me as if one of the following methods using the `choice` command utility should work for you.

Opening a `cmd` window for it to run inside:

```cmd
%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /D/Q/C "%SystemRoot%\System32\choice.exe&If ErrorLevel 2 (Exit 5)Else Exit 0"
```

Running it in the same `cmd` window:

```cmd
@%SystemRoot%\System32\choice.exe&If ErrorLevel 2 (Exit /B 5) Else Exit /B 0
```

Comment: actually i am running this script from robot framework, i want to open terminal and want to take input, based on that input and status code i will do further operation in robot script, thats why i have used that start cmd. any solution for this?

Comment: Please don't repeat comments, I did read this same information under the other answer. I do not care anything about robot framework or whatever else forms part of your project or task. You have posted a very minimal piece of code, and I have provided two options for you to incorporate into your task. What I'd therefore expect, is for you to try them, and if they fail to achieve your goal as intended, edit your question accordingly, so that we can all reproduce the same environment and issue. It's not until then, can we provide focused assistance.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to start a new `cmd` instance. As the code is right now, you also do not even require `delayedexpansion`

```
@echo off
set /P id="Enter yes or no: "
echo %id%
if /i "%id%" == "yes" (
     exit /b 0
   ) else (
     exit /b 5
)
```

Should you however require using `delayedexpansion` then use it with `setlocal` and do not start `cmd` with `/V:on` The code will be something like:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /P id="Enter yes or no: "
echo !id!
if /i "!id!" == "yes" (
     exit /b 0
   ) else (
     exit /b 5
)
```

Note, the second example above is an example, it will work, but `delayedexpansion` is not required here at all.

Should you want to use conditional operators, which acts similarly to `if` and `else` then you can simply run:

```
@echo off
set /P id="Enter yes or no: "
echo %id% | findstr /i "yes">nul && exit /b 0 || exit /b 5
```

Comment: actually i am running this script from robot framework, i want to open terminal and want to take input, based on that input and status code i will do further operation in robot script, thats why i have used that start cmd. any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I do not really understand why you are using the `start` command to run a `cmd.exe` instance to run further commands – perhaps `start` could simply be omitted.

Anyway, if you do want to use `start` you need to be aware that it actually only starts the given command line but it does not wait until the executed command line is finished, unless you specify the `/WAIT` option. Not waiting implies that the final `ErrorLevel` state cannot yet be available.

Hence the command line should probably look like this:

```cmd
start "" /WAIT cmd /V:ON /K "set /P id="Enter yes or no: " & echo(!id!& if /I "!id!"=="yes" (exit 0) else (exit 5)"`
```

You might have noticed that I changed a few more things:

- besides adding `/WAIT`, I also added an empty string `""` as the first parameter of the `start` command to specify a window title; this is necessary to safely handle command lines that could contain quotation marks (otherwise the first quoted part might erroneously be interpreted as the window title);
- `&&` lets the following command only be executed when the preceding one succeeds (hence it returns an exit code of zero), but I think you want to execute the following ones unconditionally, so I replaced `&&` by `&` for that purpose;
- `echo !id!`   returns `ECHO is ON.` or `ECHO is OFF.` when `!id!` expands to an empty string, so I used `echo(!id!` instead; then I removed the <kbd>SPACE</kbd> in front of the following `&`, which would be output too, unintentionally;
- an empty value of `!id!` would cause your `if` command line to result in a syntax error, so I introduced proper quotation; moreover, I specified a case-insensitive comparison by adding `/I`;
- finally, I replaced `exit /B` by `exit`, because the former is only needed in batch files to quit them without affecting the hosting `cmd.exe` instance, but for just quitting `cmd.exe` the latter is enough;